# Reusing the key if the IV is changed each time

Tags: encryption, cryptography, aes, aes-gcm

I am creating a program that is going to encrypt files in a folder and allow me to decrypt them later on.

I am using AES-GCM at the moment and I am wondering if using the same key but changing the IV for every encryption is the correct way to do this?

I am using mBedTLS to do this and I am able to successfully encrypt/decrypt a file using AES-GCM and hard coded key and IV. However for security reasons I want to make sure that I am changing what needs to be changed and for performance reasons, not changing something that doesn't need to be.

Comment: A different way is to use a KBKDF such as HKDF to derive another key for each file, by combining a master key and `Info`, which may be anything as long as it is unique for each file. Then you can even get away with a nonce set to all zero bytes. The advantage is that you can then choose *any* encryption scheme / mode (although using a large key size such as 256 bits may be advantageous for such schemes).

Answer (score 4):

Yup,

Even a single AES-GCM nonce reuse can be catastrophic, with the same static key.

A single nonce reuse leaks the xor of plaintexts, so if one plaintext is known the adversary can completely decrypt the other.

So you can only use the same `[nonce (IV), key]` **tuple** once per message.

It's **perfectly** **fine** to use a new nonce/IV with the **same** static key.

AES-GCM operates with a `32-bit` counter, so unfortunately with the same key, nonce (IV) pair you can only safely encrypt ~ `64GB` of data `(2^39-256 bits)`.

If you want to move to an even safer cipher, I recommend XSalsa20 or XChaCha20, which provide a `192-bit` nonce size, effectively allowing a practically "unlimited" number of messages to be encrypted with the same key, nonce pair.